# Typescript - async, await and promise are not waiting

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake DB, but the program is not waiting for the connect function to finish, and it continues although I'm using async-await.

```
async function createConnection() {
try {
    return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        // Create a Connection object that we can use later to connect.
        const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
            account: envs.account,
            username: envs.user,
            password: envs.password,
        }
        );
        // Try to connect to Snowflake, and check whether the connection was successful.
        connection.connect(
            (err, conn) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
                }
            }
        );
        resolve(connection);
    })
}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
}

async function main() {

    const connection = await createConnection();
    if (connection == undefined || !connection?.isUp()) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to snowflake...');
        return;
    }
```

The result i got is:

```
Failed to connect to snowflake...
Successfully connected to Snowflake.
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `createConnection` function and the executor function (function passed to the promise constructor) shouldn't be async. See:  [common promise anti-patterns](https://blog.yousafkhan.me/common-promise-anti-patterns)

Comment: As far as your problem is concerned, `resolve(connection);` - this statement should be _inside_ the `else` block that is inside the callback function of `connection.connect(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise should resolve to the `conn` that you can access via your callback passed into `connection.connect`.

```js
// Doesn't have to be explicitly marked `async`, if you're not using `await` inside.
function createConnection() {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        // Create a Connection object that we can use later to connect.
        const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
            account: envs.account,
            username: envs.user,
            password: envs.password,
        });

        // Try to connect to Snowflake, and check whether the connection was successful.
        connection.connect(
            (err, conn) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Unable to connect: ${err.message}`);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
                }

                // `conn` could be undefined, but your main function seems to handle that check...
                resolve(conn);
            }
        );
    });
}

async function main() {
    const connection = await createConnection();
    if (connection == undefined || !connection?.isUp()) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to snowflake...');
        return;
    }
}
```